# Obj Loader not displaying properly

Tags: c++, opengl, loader, freeglut, wavefront

so this is an obj loader in c++ using opengl
it seem displays the cube i input as a flat it seems to position them correctly but all objects i have tried come out as a plane (see pictures)

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B8AdFl9H3IJVRG9FbFo1UnpWaUE/edit?usp=sharing

i have tried other 3d objects and they all seem to come out as this plane (may difer in size)

what i have tried

- going over other obj loaders online
- slowly running through the debug
- checking the vectors load properly
- checking to see if the reading in is corect
- List item

typedef.h

```
#pragma

typedef struct {
    float x,y,z;

} points;

typedef struct {
    float vn[3];    // store the ve3rtex normals
} normal;                       


typedef struct {
    float vt[3];    // store the texture coordinates
} coordinate;


typedef struct {
    int shaders;
    points p[3];
    normal norm[3];
    coordinate coord[3];
} face;
```

loader.h

```
#pragma once

#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>

#include<iostream> // this is just for testing, you can remove this with all the cout's

#include "typedef.h"


class Loader
{
public:
    Loader(std::string input);
    ~Loader(void);

    void draw(); // this function takes the obj file and draws it

private:

    std::ifstream m_inFile;


    // the list of vectors that i will be using
    std::vector<points> m_points;
    std::vector<normal> m_normals;
    std::vector<coordinate> m_coords;
    std::vector<face> m_faces;

    void process(std::string input);

    void inputPoints(points temp);
    void inputNormals(normal temp);
    void inputCoordinates(coordinate temp);
    void createFaces(face temp);



};
```

loader.cpp

```
#include "Loader.h"


Loader::Loader(std::string input)
{
    process(input);
}


Loader::~Loader(void)
{

}

void Loader::process(std::string input)
{
    std::string identifier; //used to identify where the input should go


    points temppoint;
    normal tempnormal;
    coordinate tempcoord;
    face tempface; 


    std::string read;       // used to read the curent line

    int readNum; // this is the number that has just been read in
    char skip; // a char to skip thr /
    int i;
    int count= 1;


    m_inFile.open(input);
    /* // check to see if it read
    if(!m_inFile) 
        std::cout << "did not read";
    else
        std::cout << "file read";
    */


    //creation of the reading loop
    //while(!m_inFile.eof())
    m_inFile >> identifier;

    do {
         // check to see what the opening is

        if (identifier =="#")
        {
            getline(m_inFile,read); // use this to read the whole line

        }
        else if(identifier == "v")
        {
            m_inFile >> temppoint.x >> temppoint.y >> temppoint.z;
            inputPoints(temppoint);
        }
        else if(identifier == "vn")
        {
            m_inFile >> tempnormal.vn[0] >> tempnormal.vn[1] >> tempnormal.vn[2];
            inputNormals(tempnormal);
        }
        else if (identifier == "vt")
        {
            m_inFile >> tempcoord.vt[0] >> tempcoord.vt[1] >> tempcoord.vt[2];
            inputCoordinates(tempcoord);
        }
        else if(identifier == "f")
        {


            for( i =0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                //std::cout << "loops: " << count << std::endl;
                count++;
                //if(read == "Material.001")
                //  std::cout << std::endl;

                //std::cout << "Iteration: " << i << std::endl;
                m_inFile >> readNum;
                if(readNum == 0)
                    break;

                readNum--;

                tempface.p[i].x = m_points[readNum].x;

                tempface.p[i].y = m_points[readNum].x;

                tempface.p[i].z = m_points[readNum].z;



                m_inFile >> skip >> readNum;

                readNum--;

                tempface.coord[i].vt[0] = m_coords[readNum].vt[0];

                tempface.coord[i].vt[1] = m_coords[readNum].vt[1];

                tempface.coord[i].vt[2] = m_coords[readNum].vt[2];



                m_inFile >> skip >> readNum;

                readNum--;

                tempface.norm[i].vn[0] = m_normals[readNum].vn[0];

                tempface.norm[i].vn[1] = m_normals[readNum].vn[1];

                tempface.norm[i].vn[2] = m_normals[readNum].vn[2];



            }

            createFaces(tempface);

        }
        else 
        {
            getline(m_inFile,read);
            std::cout << "Not Processed " << identifier << " " << read <<std::endl;
        }

        m_inFile >> identifier;

    } while (!m_inFile.eof());

}

void Loader::inputPoints(points temp)
{
    m_points.push_back(temp);

}

void Loader::inputNormals(normal temp)
{
    m_normals.push_back(temp);
}

void Loader::inputCoordinates(coordinate temp)
{
    m_coords.push_back(temp);
}

void Loader::createFaces(face temp)
{
    m_faces.push_back(temp);
}

void Loader::draw()
{
    int i;
    int j;
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    for (i=0; i < m_faces.size();i++)
    {
        //std::cout<<"glBegin" <<std::endl;

        for(j = 0 ; j < 3; j++)
        {
            //std::cout << "Vn1: "<< m_faces[i].norm[j].vn[0] << "Vn2: " << m_faces[i].norm[j].vn[1] <<"Vn3: "<< m_faces[i].norm[j].vn[2] << std::endl;
            //std::cout << "X: " << m_faces[i].p[j].x << "Y: " << m_faces[i].p[j].y << "Z: " << m_faces[i].p[j].z << std::endl;
            //glNormal3f(m_faces[i].norm[j].vn[0],m_faces[i].norm[j].vn[1],m_faces[i].norm[j].vn[2]);
            glVertex3f(m_faces[i].p[j].x,m_faces[i].p[j].y,m_faces[i].p[j].z);
        }
        //glEnd();
        //std::cout << "glEnd()" << std::endl <<std::endl;
    }
    glEnd();
}
```

inside main i call a function called banner

```
void Banner()
   {




    glTranslatef(15000.0,11000.0,25000.0);
    glScalef(100,100,100);
    lod.draw();




}
```

which is badly created as a global

Comment: Also, by having the vector `m_faces` in addition to `m_points` you are effectively doubling the memory used for no apparent reason. I think you should look into creating Vertex Arrays and indices instead of the solution you have now.

Comment: Could you post a little bit more code (preferably the code where you transform your models)? I think your vertex positions may be valid, but one of your matrices (probably ModelView) may be transposed or otherwise invalid - having your model skewed into a single plane is a classic symptom of this.. By the way, is your compiler complaining about the empty `#pragma` in `typedef.h`?

Comment: First thanks again guy's, and yeah i want to destroy the vectors after i move them to face but i didn't get around to that. i'll update the code in a sec ... add the bits you asked for

Comment: You have a typo: tempface.p[i].y = m_points[readNum].x; You assign the x of what you've read to the y of tempface's position

Comment: i love you, i went over this 8 times thats guys for putting up with all my stupidity